# Multiplying matrices of same dimensions returning error

Tags: matrix, octave, matrix-multiplication

Why cannot multiply two matrices of same dimensions (1x3) ? :

```
>> a = [1 1 1]
a =

   1   1   1

>> b = [1 1 1]
b =

   1   1   1

>> a * b
error: operator *: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 1x3, op2
is 1x3)
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` is the matrix multiplication operator so if `A` is an `n`-by-`m` matrix and `B` is an `x`-by-`y` matrix for

```
A*B
```

to be valid you need the inner dimension to match in size thus `m` must equal `x`. Or said another way, the number of columns of `A` (in your case `3`) must equal the number of columns of `B` (in your case `1`).

Some solutions:

You wanted the [inner product](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Dot_product):

```
A*B.'      % result is a scalar (1-by-1)
```

or the [outer product](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Outer_product):

```
A.'*B      % result is a 3-by-3 matrix
```

Or else you wanted the element-wise multiplication (i.e. multiply each element with it's corresponding element, assuming the two matrices have the identical size) which is the `.*` operator:

```
A.*B       % result is a 1-by-3
```

Answer (score 0):

Matrix dimensions should match: the columns of the second matrix must be the same number rows of the first matrix. For your case, you can multiply `a*b^T` or `a^T*b`, depending on what you're trying to achieve.  There is also Hadamard product (elementwise multiplication) but it's not considered as matrix multiplication.